# How to fill the missing values for a column based on multiple conditions to be met in other columns in the pandas dataframe using chaining?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, conditional-statements

I have dataframe `df` which can be recreated using the code below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"CLIENT_ID": [8222, 8222, 8222, 8222, 8300, 8300, 8300, 8300, 8300, 8400, 8401, 8401, 8500],
                   "ENCOUNTER_DATE": ['2020-01-01', '2020-03-02', '2020-04-18', '2020-07-31', '2017-06-10', '2017-09-11', '2018-02-01', '2018-04-01', '2018-05-31', '2020-12-31', '2017-08-29', '2017-09-15', '2018-10-10'],
                   "STAGE": ['STAGE1', np.NaN, 'STAGE1', 'STAGE1', np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN,np.NaN, 'STAGE2'],
                   "Status": ['Healthy', 'Asymptomatic', 'Asymptomatic','Asymptomatic', 'Extremely Ill', 'Extremely Ill', 'Extremely Ill', 'Extremely Ill', 'Extremely Ill', np.NaN, 'Asymptomatic', 'Asymptomatic', 'Mild Sickness']})
```

which results in the output below:

| CLIENT_ID | ENCOUNTER_DATE | STAGE | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8222 | 2020-01-01 | STAGE1 | Healthy |
| 8222 | 2020-03-02 | NaN | Asymptomatic |
| 8222 | 2020-04-18 | STAGE1 | Asymptomatic |
| 8222 | 2020-07-31 | STAGE1 | Asymptomatic |
| 8300 | 2017-06-10 | NaN | Extremely Ill |
| 8300 | 2017-09-11 | NaN | Extremely Ill |
| 8300 | 2018-02-01 | NaN | Extremely Ill |
| 8300 | 2018-04-01 | NaN | Extremely Ill |
| 8300 | 2018-05-31 | NaN | Extremely Ill |
| 8400 | 2020-12-31 | NaN | NaN |
| 8401 | 2017-08-29 | NaN | Asymptomatic |
| 8401 | 2017-09-15 | NaN | Asymptomatic |
| 8500 | 2018-10-10 | STAGE2 | Mild Sickness |

The data is sorted and grouped by `CLIENT_ID` and `ENCOUNTER_DATE`. I want to fill the missing values in the `STAGE` by using the entry of the `Status` field for each `CLIENT_ID.

1. **1st condition:**

If `Status = Asymptomatic or Healthy` then `STAGE = STAGE1`, if `Status = Mild Sickness` then `STAGE = STAGE2` and if `STATUS = Extremely Ill` then `STAGE = STAGE3`

2. **2nd condition:**

If `Status` and `STAGE` are  both`null`, THEN `STAGE = STAGE1`

Is it possible to use `np.select` or would `df.loc` suffice?

The result would be like below:

| CLIENT_ID | ENCOUNTER_DATE | STAGE | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8222 | 2020-01-01 | STAGE1 | Healthy |
| 8222 | 2020-03-02 | STAGE1 | Asymptomatic |
| 8222 | 2020-04-18 | STAGE1 | Asymptomatic |
| 8222 | 2020-07-31 | STAGE1 | Asymptomatic |
| 8300 | 2017-06-10 | STAGE3 | Extremely Ill |
| 8300 | 2017-09-11 | STAGE3 | Extremely Ill |
| 8300 | 2018-02-01 | STAGE3 | Extremely Ill |
| 8300 | 2018-04-01 | STAGE3 | Extremely Ill |
| 8300 | 2018-05-31 | STAGE3 | Extremely Ill |
| 8400 | 2020-12-31 | STAGE1 | NaN |
| 8401 | 2017-08-29 | STAGE1 | Asymptomatic |
| 8401 | 2017-09-15 | STAGE1 | Asymptomatic |
| 8500 | 2018-10-10 | STAGE2 | Mild Sickness |

Answer (score -1):

```
statuses = {'Healthy': 'STAGE1', 'Asymptomatic': 'STAGE1', 'Extremely Ill': 'STAGE3'}
df.loc[df['STAGE'].isnull(), 'STAGE'] = df[df['STAGE'].isnull()]['Status'].map(statuses)
df.loc[(df['STAGE'].isnull()) & (df['Status'].isnull()), 'STAGE'] = 'STAGE1'
```

OUTPUT

```
    CLIENT_ID ENCOUNTER_DATE   STAGE         Status
0        8222     2020-01-01  STAGE1        Healthy
1        8222     2020-03-02  STAGE1   Asymptomatic
2        8222     2020-04-18  STAGE1   Asymptomatic
3        8222     2020-07-31  STAGE1   Asymptomatic
4        8300     2017-06-10  STAGE3  Extremely Ill
5        8300     2017-09-11  STAGE3  Extremely Ill
6        8300     2018-02-01  STAGE3  Extremely Ill
7        8300     2018-04-01  STAGE3  Extremely Ill
8        8300     2018-05-31  STAGE3  Extremely Ill
9        8400     2020-12-31  STAGE1            NaN
10       8401     2017-08-29  STAGE1   Asymptomatic
11       8401     2017-09-15  STAGE1   Asymptomatic
12       8500     2018-10-10  STAGE2  Mild Sickness
```